# How can I use parents('ul') to select the nearest/ closest <ul> only?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, parents

I have this html,

```
<ul>
  <li>A
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How can I use `parents('ul')` to select the nearest/ closest `<ul>` only but not the toppest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the closest parent, just use `parents('ul:first')`.

Comment: @lauthiamkok - Just in case, here's a working example: [http://jsfiddle.net/cy3yv/](http://jsfiddle.net/cy3yv/).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context:

```
$('li a').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent('ul');

    // OR...

    var parent = $(this).parents('ul')[0];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at get? http://api.jquery.com/get/ You can try

```
$('li').parents('ul').get(0);
```

Comment: not yet but I think Francois Deschenes's answer is the easiest! thank you! :-)